# my linux suse 13.6.2 is missing a directory

Tags: linux, installation, suse, wifi

I downloaded Suse Linux 32bit 3.16.6.2.0 as an iso, burned a DVD and installed it as a dual OS with my Win 7.  Now, to get the WLan Stick to work....
Using the Win OS I downloaded two files : 
           ndiswrapper-1.59.tar.gz and fwlanusb-1.00.00.tar.gz

I moved them into the Linux partition and ran the ./install files as instructed.

With *both* of these installation it requires running a makefile script.  In *both* cases it comes to a crashing stop when /lib/modules/kernel3.16.6.2.0/build is not found.

The 'build' subdirectiory or file is not present.  Can I call up one of the rpms to get this part of the Linux OS installed?? Which rpm??

Solving the problem with my WLAN Stick is especially hard because often the Linux documentation says : "in order to make you your internet connection function you must **download** xyz".

Comment: This question is a more general computing question than it is programming-related so it’s *off-topic* for StackOverflow and more appropriate for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Please install the `kernel-source` RPM for your running kernel. If this doesn't help already, please make sure that a symlink from `/lib/modules/kernel3.16.6.2.0/build` to `/usr/src/linux` exists.